# Laravel - Dusk - preg_match_all() - Undefined offset: 0 без видимых причин

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, laravel

Есть браузерный тест.

В нём я беру строку из HTML-элемента и паршу её:

```php
preg_match_all('=\d+$=', $subject, $matches);
```

Пример строки:

> Please use this verification code to complete your sign in: 
>    123456

Потом хочу взять весь шаблон: `$matches[0][0]`; но выдаёт следующее:

> ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0

Пробую положить в лог: `Log::info($matches);`

В логе:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '123456',
  ),
)
```

Есть идеи?

**P. S.** Так: `array_shift($matches[0]);`; работает.

Comment: `$mathces[0][0]` если вы это скопировали, то проверьте написание имени переменной

Comment: @teran, это я опечатался просто в коде: не в этом проблема. Спасибо, что поправили. Исправил.

Comment: Решается с помощью `array_shift($matches[0]);`, но хотелось бы узнать, что это за мистика.

Comment: приведите весь код, ошибка в другом месте где-то возникает у вас. и отметьте строку на которую пхп указывает в сообщении об ошибке

Comment: Не понятно почему массив многомерный, разве не так должен быть вызов `$matches[0]`

Comment: @PotroNik, https://repl.it/@w3lifer/TangibleCostlyInterfaces

Comment: @PotroNik потому что там не `preg_match` а `preg_match_all`

Comment: зачем кстати вам `preg_match_all` ?

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения за то, что некромант, но вопрос открыт - хотелось бы расставить точки.

Дело в том, что иногда массив $matches бывает пуст, поэтому перед вызовом элементов массива необходимо делать проверку:

```
 $subjects = [
     'эта строка будет иметь совпадения: 123456',
     'а эта даст ошибку!'
 ];

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    preg_match_all('=\d+$=', $subject, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[0]) && !empty($matches[0][0])) {
        var_dump($matches[0][0]);
    } else {
        echo'no matches' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

вывод:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/projects/examples$ php aaa.php
/home/vagrant/projects/examples/aaa.php:39:
string(6) "123456"
no matches
vagrant@homestead:~/projects/examples$
```